# some intuition about the degree of a map

Tags: complex-geometry, moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces, homology, equivariant

Consider a map
$$ f: \Sigma \to X/\sigma,$$
where $\Sigma=\Sigma_g/\Omega$ is a quotient of a Riemann surface by an antiholomorphic involution,
$\sigma:X\to X$ is an antiholomorphic involution
of some CY threefold $X$
(with pointwise fixed set $L$)
and the holomorphic map $\hat f: \Sigma_g \to \Sigma_g$
is equivariant, $\hat f \circ \Omega = \sigma \circ \hat f$,
and descends to $f$.

How can we get a nice intuition about the degree
$$d := f_* ([\Sigma]) \in H_2(X,L;\mathbb{Z}),$$
namely is it true e.g. that $d=\sum d_i$ where each $d_i$ comes either from a boundary or a crosscap (i.e. an $\mathbb{RP}^2$) of $\Sigma$,
and thus it is somehow 'localized' on $L$?

(this question has a double on math.SE)